# Trees with Django models - different approaches

Tags: python, django, tree, nodes

I'm trying to make a simple tree app that accepts a user's input and adds nodes to a tree structure based on the input.  I want every node of the tree to be an instance of a general model, called nodes.

An entry has up to two parts: a parent, which is the beginning of the string up to the first parentheses, and a child, which is in parentheses.

For example, let's say a user enters the following:

```
"animal(cat)"
"animal(dog)"
"dog(golden retriever)"
"organic_life_form(animal)"
```

This should generate a tree of this structure:

```
organic_life_form
        |
     animal
   /         \
dog            cat
  |
golden retriever
```

I made a mistake defining my 'node' model, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Node)
    nodes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Apparently I am not allowed to use another node as my foreign key "parent", as "Node" isn't yet defined.  This seems like a pretty basic error, but I still don't understand why one isn't allowed to do this.

Can anyone explain why I am unable to use another "Node" as a foreign key?  And if it's a lost cause, what might be a better way of defining the type of structure I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node isn't available within the class definition, as it has not yet been defined. To permit this, Django allows you to use the name as a string in quotes.

However for your underlying problem you should probably look into an existing library like django-mptt.

Comment: Actually I am trying this myself in order to learn, so I'll try this without an existing library.  It seems like there should be other ways of modeling the structure I am concerned with, but I can't think of any.

Comment: As I say, using `"Node"` rather than just `Node` allows you to use your current approach

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
parent = models.ForeignKey("self")
```